# Update Statement from a select using a left join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this query here

```
SELECT a.FileTrackingTag, a.DataSetName FROM TempTable a
LEFT JOIN FinalTable b ON a.Title = b.Title
WHERE b.FileTrackingTag IS NULL
AND b.DataSetName IS NULL
```

And I want to update the Filetrackingtag and the datasetname in finaltable with the values in temptable only if they are null and having the same Title and SampleID between the two tables

table structure is as such,
both tables have Title, Filetrackingtag, and Datasetname

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the statement you're looking for is this:

```
UPDATE f SET
    Filetrackingtag = isnull(f.Filetrackingtag, t.Filetrackingtag),
    Datasetname  = isnull(f.Datasetname, t.Datasetname)
FROM FinalTable f
JOIN TempTable t 
    ON f.Title = t.Title and f.SampleID = t.SampleID
```

*(I haven't tested the code, but I'm pretty confident it should work)*

Answer (score 1):

Use derived table in UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE x
SET x.FileTrackingTag = x.newFileTrackingTag,
    x.DataSetName = x.newDataSetName
FROM (
      SELECT a.FileTrackingTag AS newFileTrackingTag, a.DataSetName AS newDataSetName,
             b.FileTrackingTag, b.DataSetName
      FROM TempTable a LEFT JOIN FinalTable b ON a.Title = b.Title AND a.SampleID = b.SampleID
      WHERE b.FileTrackingTag IS NULL AND b.DataSetName IS NULL
      ) x
```